# How much space IIS appropriate for Sessions in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

How much space IIS 6 and 7 appropriate to any asp.net application for sessions?

have this space limitation?

thanks

Comment: space? are you talking about ram?

Comment: I know that session are stored in Server.but I don't know where and how much

Comment: it can be configured. they are stored in memory, but you can set the server to store them in SQL Server too, probably depending on your needs. i think the memory is limited by ASP.NET's normal memory limits. in other words, i've never heard of a "special memory limit for session data"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, In-Process Mode is limited only by the RAM available on the server. Do you have specific concerns that you might exceed available RAM? If so, either increase your RAM or use an alternative session state mode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are so called sessionstateprovider. So you can actually choose. The ones I'm aware of are:

- In memory
- Session state service
- SQL server
- Velocity

Velocity is a distributed caching that can be used as session state container. I think it's now called or part of AppFabric.

The size of a session depends on your app. There is no real hard limit I know of. The best thing is to keep it as small as possible, but again, even large sessions could be required and if planned for are probably no problem.